# Параллельная загрузка объектов на сцене

Tags: c#, unity3d

При проигрыше игрока переносит на нулевую сцену :

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
```

Но фишка в том, что объекты загружаются по очереди (что не очень круто).
Вопрос:Как я могу загрузить их по параллельно?

P.S.: Да,я знаю что можно сделать заставку между сценами, но сами уровни не рассчитаны на долгое время игры и делать заставку между сценами не очень.

Если есть другие варианты буду рад выслушать.

Comment: Что значит "объекты загружаются по очереди"? У вас подгружается вся сцена, параллельно ее загрузить невозможно чисто физически, сцена - это, грубо говоря, набор файлов, каким образом можно "параллельно" загрузить эти файлы с постоянного носителя? Хотите быстрее - запускайте всю игру в одной сцене и подгружайте необходимые файлы на ходу или держите постоянно в памяти, а в нужный момент из памяти и читайте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если уровни маленькие, то тебе достаточно загрузить твою основную сцену + все ожидаемые:

```
//асинхронно грузим сцену 3
AsyncOperation scene3AsyncOperation = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("Scene3");
//не загружаем сцену по окончанию загрузки
scene3AsyncOperation.allowSceneActivation = false;
```

а в момент когда нужно переключится на нужную сцену

```
scene3AsyncOperation.allowSceneActivation = true;
```

и тогда загрузка будет моментальной.

но ничего лишнего так не подгружай т.к. каждая загруженная сцена жрет ресурсы.

Comment: Да,уровни маленькие , но их много . Я боюсь что если подключить все уровни , то нагрузка на телефон будет очень высокой , только если загружать каждый раз нулевую сцену при переходе на след. лвл , но есть ли смысл?(уровни то проходятся за 5-10 сек.)

Comment: держи нулевую сцену всегда загруженной, а остальные подгружай аддитивно ( `SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneToLoad, LoadSceneMode.Additive);` ) и выгружай ( `UnloadScene(sceneName);`) по мере надобности.